# How to remap control keys in MS Layout Creator

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout, key-binding

**edit**: I successfully user KeyTweak to remap the keys. However doing so remaps them for all keyboard layouts. Is there a way to remap them only for my custom layout (created, as I said earlier, with MS Layout Creator), and leaving them intact for other layouts?

---

I'm using an Apple Wide Keyboard, and I've remapped most keys to my tastes using [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665), however apparently it won't let me remap neither the modifier keys nor some keys on the right part of the keyboard.

ps: sharpkeys isn't working very nice, doesn't detect left alt at all, neither fn or eject.

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable writing scripts, try [AutoHotkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) . As I have no Apple Wide Keyboard, I can't tell you the codes for the keys you listed, but if you run AutoHotkey, double-click on the systray icon, press Ctrl+K, press those keys then press F5 to see a list of the most recent keys pressed. For info on writing your script, see [this AutoHotkey tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm).

Comment: Going to try, thx

Comment: AutoHotkey was quite confusing, however its help pointed me out to use KeyTweak, which did work. I'm going to re-elaborate my question, but if I don't get new answers I'll just give the bounty here.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, Lohoris. Hope KeyTweak has worked out for you.

Comment: I found a script for ahk to do this, but it doesn't work on win7 64 bit (using ahk64). The original requires DLLCalls to user32.dll to get the current keyboard layout. Haven't found a fix yet.